# Switch on interface type without type assertion

Tags: go, switch-statement

I have a function that can take a number of different argument types. I'd like to use a type switch and reduce code duplication as much as possible. As a very basic example, here I want to copy both `uint8` and `int8` types into a byte buffer. This code happily works

```golang
package main

func switchFn(args ...interface{}) {
    var buf []byte
    for _, arg := range args {
        switch val := arg.(type) {
        case uint8:
            buf = append(buf, byte(val))
        case int8:
            buf = append(buf, byte(val))
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    switchFn(int8(42), uint8(42)) // etc
}
```

You'll notice both the case statements do exactly the same thing! If I combine them though...

```golang
package main

func switchFn(args ...interface{}) {
    var buf []byte
    for _, arg := range args {
        switch val := arg.(type) {
        case uint8, int8:
            buf = append(buf, byte(val))
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    switchFn(int8(42), uint8(42)) // etc
}
```

I run into an issue of `cannot convert val (type interface {}) to type byte: need type assertion`. But I'm literally switching on the type! Argh!

Am I stuck with the code duplication here, or is there a smarter way to do this? Note that the *copying into byte buffer* is used to illustrate the example, my function may be doing other things in the case blocks.

Comment: no, those are different types, so require different cases.

Comment: To reduce code duplication, move the case block to a function and call the function from both cases.

Comment: `case uint8, int8:` is that a valid way to match multiple cases anywhere in Go?  Can't find any mention in the spec

Comment: @DanielFarrell, that’s valid as a case, but because it could be either type the value is still going to be an interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cases can be combined, but `val` will have type `interface{}` in the block. That's not useful for your scenario.

Use a function to reduce code duplication.

```
func switchFn(args ...interface{}) {
    var buf []byte

    byteFn := func(b byte) {
        buf = append(buf, b)
    }

    for _, arg := range args {
        switch val := arg.(type) {
        case uint8:
            byteFn(val)
        case int8:
            byteFn(byte(val))
        }
    }
}
```

The `reflect` API will not help because separate code is required for the signed and unsigned values.  The `reflect` API is helpful for combining all signed integers into block of code and all unsigned integers into another block of code.

```
for _, arg := range args {
    switch val := arg.(type) {
    case int, int8, int16, int32, int64:
        i := reflect.ValueOf(val).Int()
        // i is an int64
        fmt.Println(i)
    case uint, uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64:
        u := reflect.ValueOf(val).Uint()
        // u is an uint64
        fmt.Println(u)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to avoid the code duplication, at the cost of ... well, a different sort of code duplication:

```golang
func switchFn(args ...interface{}) {
    var buf []byte
    for _, arg := range args {
        var val byte
        switch v := arg.(type) {
        case uint8:
            val = byte(v)
        case int8:
            val = byte(v)
        default:
            panic("wrong type")
        }
        buf = append(buf, val)
    }
}
```

For this particular function, the original duplication is probably better.  Should the `buf = append(buf, val)` section get larger or more complicated, this would probably be better.

In still other cases—perhaps most real ones—the method [gopher suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69621750/switch-on-interface-type-without-type-assertion#comment123060440_69621750) is probably best:

```golang
    f := func(val byte) {
        buffer = append(buffer, val)
    }
```

You can now call `f` from each `case`.